# Store single property from GraphQL query in local Apollo store

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

In my React app when a user goes to `myapp.com/org/companyname` it loads a page with the following logic to get some basic details about the company based on the company name in the URL:

```js
const FIND_COMPANY = gql`
  query CompanyQuery($companyName: String!) {
    company(name: $companyName) {
      ... on Company {
        name
        description
      }
      ... on Error {
        errorMessage
      }
    }
  }
`;

<Query
  query={FIND_COMPANY}
  variables={{
    companyName: this.props.location.pathname.split("org/")[1]
  }}
>
  {({ data }) => {
    if (data.company.errorMessage)
      return <div>{data.company.errorMessage}</div>;

    return (
     <div>
       <h1>{data.company.name}</h1>
       <p>{data.company.description}</p>
     </div>
    );
  }}
</Query>
```

This works fine, however I want to store just the currently company name in the local Apollo state so that it can be easily accessed by other components without having to do string manipulation on the URL in each component.

To do this I've followed the ['Direct writes'](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state.html#direct-writes) section of the Apollo local state docs and ended up with the following:

```js
<ApolloConsumer>
  {client => (
    <Query
      query={FIND_COMPANY}
      variables={{
        companyName: this.props.location.pathname.split("org/")[1]
      }}
      onCompleted={data =>
        client.writeData({ data: { companyName: data.company.name } })
      }
    >
      {({ data }) => {
        if (data.company.errorMessage)
          return <div>{data.company.errorMessage}</div>;

        return (
        <div>
          <h1>{data.company.name}</h1>
          <p>{data.company.description}</p>
        </div>
        );
      }}
    </Query>
  }
</ApolloConsumer>
```

Where I write just the company name to the Apollo local state `onCompleted`. However, when I run this it crashes the app.

Is this the correct way to store local state in Apollo or have I misunderstood how local Apollo state should be used?

Comment: The query is already stored,why want you to store the result again. If you need the info in other places just use the exact same query and apollo will get the data out of the store instead of make a backend call. Also if you would use an `id` in your company object, you could use `readFragment` to get only the company out of the store.

Comment: The main thing I wanted to avoid was having to do the string manipulation on the URL to get the company name to run the query, but I'm using `react-router` so I've replaced that with `match.params.companyName`. I think trying to avoid that led me down the path of wanting to store the value elsewhere, which wasn't correct.

Thanks for the tip about using `readFragment`.